# how to use re.sub to replace matches with a series of numbers

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-re

I'm trying to remove all HTML tags from a text file and after some processing on the text , I have to put the HTML tags back in the text, So i thought maybe replacing HTML tags with a series of numbers for example 1 to n (with a pair of '#' in the beginning ) which can be ignored easily when processing the text would be a good solution.
The problem is when i try to use **re.sub** it will replace all the matches with the last number

Here is the code:

```
def remove_tags(raw_html,len):
    bb = [x for x in range(l)]

    for i in range(len):
        clean_text = re.sub(html_pattern, '##'+str(bb[i]), raw_html)
    return clean_text
```

*l is the number of tags in the text*

any other methods are appreciated.
(maybe even merging the original text and the processed one together with out the strings and only the HTML tags in the right spot)

edit: I've attached a sample input that I'm working with

```
                        <div class="post-module__content">
                            <div>
<p>کسب موفقیت یکی از ارکان اصلی داشتن یک زندگی باکیفیت محسوب می‌شود. انسان‌ها ذاتا موجوداتی اجتماعی هستند و هنگامی که در جامعه در کنار سایر هم‌نوعانشان قرار می‌گیرند، میل شدیدی به قرار گرفتن در بالاترین نقطه‌ی سلسله‌مراتب اجتماعی پیدا می‌کنند. از دیرباز تا کنون، کسب موفقیت به عنوان یکی از باارزش‌ترین و ستودنی‌ترین موارد تلاش بشر در جوامع مختلف، از اهمیت بسیاری برخوردار بوده است. با این وجود، گهگاه فشار وارده بر انسان برای داشتن اهداف والایی که قادر هستند او را به سمت موفقیت سوق دهند به قدری زیاد می‌شود که میل به کسب موفقیت جای خود را به ترس از موفقیت می‌دهد.</p>
<p>نکته‌ی قابل تأمل در رابطه با پدیده‌ی ترس از موفقیت این است که مفهوم موفقیت به‌خودی‌خود هراس‌برانگیز نیست. در واقع، ترسی که در قلب عواقب احتمالی ناشی از دست‌یابی به موفقیت واقع شده است آن را تبدیل به پدیده‌ای ناخوشایند می‌کند. با هر بار کسب موفقیت، انتظارهای دیگران برای کسب موفقیت‌های بزرگ‌تر بیشتر می‌شود و به موازات آن، نگرانی در خصوص از دست دادن آرامش به قیمت ارتقای موقعیت اجتماعی هم افزایش می‌یابد. با این اوصاف، می‌توان به جرأت گفت که بروز پدیده‌ی ترس از موفقیت بی‌خود و بی‌جهت نیست.</p>
<p>در این مقاله از دیجی‌کالا مگ، ضمن معرفی ویژگی‌های این پدیده، راهکارهایی برای شناسایی و درمان آن ارائه می‌کنیم. با ما همراه باشید.</p>
</div>
<div id="mntl-sc-block_1-0-7" class="comp mntl-sc-block mntl-sc-block-adslot mntl-block">
<div id="mntl-native_1-0" class="comp mntl-native" data-right-rail-index="1">
<h2 id="mntl-native__adunit_1-0" class="comp scads-to-load mntl-native__adunit mntl-gpt-dynamic-adunit mntl-gpt-adunit gpt native dynamic js-immediate-ad">ویژگی‌های پدیده‌ی ترس از موفقیت</h2>
</div>
</div>
<p>تشخیص پدیده‌ی ترس از موفقیت کار چندان راحتی نیست، اما ویژگی‌هایی هستند که در صورت یافتن‌شان در شخصیت خود یا دیگران، می‌توانید آن‌ها را به ترس از موفقیت نسبت دهید. در ادامه، ۴ مورد از این ویژگی‌ها معرفی شده‌اند.</p>
<h3 id="mntl-sc-block_1-0-9" class="comp mntl-sc-block mntl-sc-block-adslot mntl-block">۱. بی‌انگیزگی</h3>
<p>شاید عجیب به نظر برسد اما یکی از راهکارهای مؤثر برای دوری از مرکز توجه دیگران بودن و کم کردن سطح توقع‌های آن‌ها، ابراز بی‌انگیزگی و نداشتن هدف خاصی در زندگی است. اگر در گذشته موفقیت‌های چشم‌گیری کسب کرده باشید، به احتمال زیاد در تیررس دید افراد بسیاری قرار دارید که شاید بسیاری از آن‌ها را حتی نشناسید! در چنین شرایطی، فشار وارده برای کسب موفقیت‌های بزرگ‌تر می‌تواند به قدری زیاد شود که ترس از موفقیت عاقلانه‌تر از سخت‌کوشی به نظر برسد.</p>
<div>
<ul>
<li class="_txt entry-title"><a href="https://www.digikala.com/mag/10-effective-actions-to-motivate/">۱۰ روش ساده و مؤثر برای ایجاد انگیزه</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<h3>۲. تسلیم شدن</h3>
<p>به دنبال بروز بی‌انگیزگی، تمایل به تسلیم شدن چنان ظاهر فریبنده و جذابی به خود می‌گیرد که ترس از موفقیت را برای لحظه‌ای توجیه می‌کند. این نوع تسلیم شدن خود را به گونه‌های مختلفی جلوه می‌دهد. گاهی شخص در مسیر درستی قرار دارد و فشار روحی و بار مسؤولیت او را وادار به نیمه‌تمام گذاشتن راه می‌کند و گاهی تصمیم می‌گیرد پیش از قرار گرفتن در مسیر منتهی به موفقیت، تسلیم شدن را برگزیند و از انتخاب مسیر درست بازبماند. در هر دو صورت، ترس از موفقیت به شخص غلبه کرده و احساس بیهودگی را تشدید می‌کند.</p>
<h3>۳. اهمال‌کاری</h3>
<p><img loading="lazy" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-1085825" src="./sample_files/procrastination.png" alt="اهمال‌کاری ناشی از ترس از موفقیت" width="822" height="522" srcset="https://www.digikala.com/mag/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/procrastination.png 822w, https://www.digikala.com/mag/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/procrastination-300x191.png 300w, https://www.digikala.com/mag/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/procrastination-768x488.png 768w, https://www.digikala.com/mag/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/procrastination-190x122.png 190w, https://www.digikala.com/mag/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/procrastination-120x76.png 120w, https://www.digikala.com/mag/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/procrastination-265x168.png 265w, https://www.digikala.com/mag/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/procrastination-284x180.png 284w, https://www.digikala.com/mag/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/procrastination-274x173.png 274w, https://www.digikala.com/mag/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/procrastination-220x140.png 220w" sizes="(max-width: 822px) 100vw, 822px"></p>
<p>یکی از مهم‌ترین پایه‌های کسب موفقیت، انجام کار درست در زمان و مکان درست است. اگر کاری به درستی انجام شود اما در زمان معین‌شده ارائه نشود، نمی‌توان آن را تضمین‌کننده‌ی موفقیت دانست. معمولا زمانی که انجام فعالیتی با اهمال‌کاری همراه شود، نتیجه‌ی خوبی حاصل نمی‌شود. اهمال‌کاری یکی از علائم پدیدار شدن ترس از موفقیت است، چراکه شخص با عقب انداختن انجام کارها، به دیگران ثابت می‌کند که تمام توجهش را معطوف مسؤولیتی که به او واگذار شده نکرده است و سعی دارد به خاطر ترس از موفقیت سطح توقع‌های دیگران را به حداقل برساند.</p>
<ul>
<li class="_txt entry-title"><a href="https://www.digikala.com/mag/overcoming-pandemic-procrastination/">۶ گام مؤثر برای غلبه بر تنبلی و اهمال‌کاری ناشی از آن</a></li>
</ul>
<h3>۴. خودتخریبی</h3>
<p>افرادی که از موفقیت می‌ترسند، ممکن است موانعی را به شیوه‌های مختلف بر سر راه موفقیت خود قرار دهند تا رسیدن به مقصد را کند و دشوار کنند. این رفتارهای خودتخریب‌گرایانه انواع و شدت‌های مختلفی دارند، اما معمولا به شکل تضعیف عزت‌نفس و اعتمادبه‌نفس توسط خود شخص بروز پیدا می‌کنند و با گذر زمان و افزایش میزان ترس از موفقیت شدت می‌گیرند.</p>
<p id="mntl-sc-block_1-0-11" class="comp mntl-sc-block mntl-sc-block-adslot mntl-block">آنچه در خصوص بررسی پدیده‌‌ی ترس از موفقیت پیچیده و در مواقعی غیرقابل‌درک است، تمایز قائل شدن میان ترس از شکست خوردن و بی‌حوصلگی برای انجام وظایف است. در موارد بسیاری، افرادی که ترس از موفقیت دارند به چشم دیگران تنبل، بی‌انگیزه و بی‌نظم جلوه می‌کنند! بنابراین، می‌توان با قاطعیت گفت که تشخیص صحیح و به‌موقع این ترس می‌تواند به بهبود علائم آن کمک چشمگیری کند. در ادامه، شیوه‌های شناسایی و تشخیص پدیده‌ی ترس از موفقیت و دلایل به وجود آمدن آن را شرح می‌دهیم.</p>
<h2 id="mntl-sc-block_1-0-12" class="comp mntl-sc-block health-sc-block-heading mntl-sc-block-heading"><span class="mntl-sc-block-heading__text">شناسایی و تشخیص پدیده‌ی ترس از موفقیت</span></h2>
<p id="mntl-sc-block_1-0-14" class="comp mntl-sc-block mntl-sc-block-adslot mntl-block">اگر شک دارید که آنچه حس می‌کنید ترس از موفقیت است یا تنبلی و بی‌حوصلگی، به نشانه‌های زیر توجه کنید. اگر توانستید سه مورد (یا بیشتر) را در خود بیابید، به احتمال زیاد شما هم اسیر ترس از موفقیت شده‌اید.</p>
<ul>
<li id="mntl-sc-block_1-0-16" class="comp mntl-sc-block mntl-sc-block-adslot mntl-block">از اینکه پس از قرار گرفتن در مرکز توجه چه اتفاق‌هایی ممکن است بیفتد به شدت می‌ترسید.</li>
<li>از احتمال کسب موفقیت و به دنبال آن فراموش کردن یا رها کردن افرادی که دوستشان دارید واهمه دارید.</li>
<li>پذیرش مسؤولیت‌های جدیدی که هر موفقیت به طور طبیعی به دنبال دارد برایتان دشوار است.</li>
<li>از پیچیده شدن همه چیز به قدری که باعث شود کنترل امور را از دست بدهید بیزارید.</li>
<li>از شنیدن نظرهای دیگران راجع به کیفیت عملکردتان یا تجربه‌ی دشواری‌های اجتماعی دیگر می‌ترسید.</li>
</ul>
<p id="mntl-sc-block_1-0-18" class="comp mntl-sc-block mntl-sc-block-adslot mntl-block">گاهی افرادی که از ترس از موفقیت رنج می‌برند متوجه رفتارهای خودتخریب‌گرایانه‌ی خود می‌شوند اما به دلیل اینکه نمی‌توانند آن‌ها را ریشه‌یابی کنند، از بهبود شرایط بازمی‌مانند. در چنین شرایطی، بهترین راهکار مراجعه به روان‌درمانگر و توصیف وضعیت کنونی زندگی است. روان‌درمانگران می‌توانند ریشه‌ی ترس از موفقیت را پیدا کنند و به شخص آسیب‌دیده کمک کنند تا به تدریج عملکرد خود را ارتقا دهد و مسیر موفقیت را از سر بگیرد.</p>
<h2>دلایل بروز ترس از موفقیت</h2>
<p id="mntl-sc-block_1-0-23" class="comp mntl-sc-block mntl-sc-block-adslot mntl-block">ترس از موفقیت می‌تواند دلایل زیادی داشته باشد که در ادامه، چند مورد از آن‌ها شرح داده شده‌اند.</p>
<ul>
<li><strong><a href="https://www.digikala.com/mag/imposter-syndrome/">سندروم ایمپاستِر</a>:</strong> بعضی افراد پس از کسب موفقیت با خود می‌اندیشند که لیاقت موفقیت را نداشته‌اند یا اینکه به اندازه‌ی دیگر افراد فعال در حیطه‌های مشابه برای به دست آوردن نتایج عالی زحمت نکشیده‌اند. در چنین مواقعی، ترس از برآورده نکردن انتظارهای دیگران یا ضعیف ظاهر شدن در مسیرهای چالش‌برانگیز می‌تواند باعث بروز ترس از موفقیت شود.</li>
<li><strong>شدید بودن احساس‌های وابسته به موفقیت:</strong> احساس هیجان و اضطراب نمودهای جسمی بسیار مشابهی دارند و در مواقعی، تشخیص آن‌ها از یکدیگر دشوار است. شدید بودن احساس هیجان ناشی از کسب موفقیت ممکن است به عنوان عاملی بازدارنده عمل کند و فرد را از موقعیت‌هایی که می‌توانند محرکی برای بروز این احساس باشند دور کند.</li>
<li><strong>ترس از تنش:</strong> گاهی ترس از موفقیت به دلیل هراس داشتن از عواقب اجتماعی احتمالی پدید می‌آید که ممکن است در اثر کسب موفقیت گریبان‌گیر شخص شود. محققان این پدیده را «دوری‌جویی از تنش» می‌نامند. گاهی گرفتن ترفیع در محل کار یا به دست آوردن موقعیتی مناسب برای ارتقای وضعیت مالی پیامدهای منفی به دنبال دارد که خود را در ظاهر کینه‌توزی اطرافیان نشان می‌دهند. این پیامدهای منفی نقش بسیار مؤثری در بروز ترس از موفقیت ایفا می‌کنند.</li>
<li id="mntl-sc-block_1-0-25" class="comp mntl-sc-block mntl-sc-block-adslot mntl-block"><strong>تجربه‌های منفی در گذشته:</strong> گاهی داشتن تجربه‌های منفی مرتبط با کسب موفقیت در گذشته می‌تواند روی طرز فکر شخص تأثیر بگذارد و به عبارتی او را محتاط‌تر کند. جلوه کردن به عنوان شخصی که جنبه‌ی کسب موفقیت را ندارد یا دستاوردهایش را توجیهی برای خودبرتربینی تلقی می‌کند به هیچ عنوان خوشایند نیست. ترس از اینگونه به نظر آمدن با بروز ترس از موفقیت رابطه‌ی مستقیم دارد.</li>
<li><strong>خودکارآمدی ضعیف:</strong> خودکارآمدی به فعالیت‌هایی که شخص در زمان حال برای تأمین آینده‌ی بهتر انجام می‌دهد اشاره دارد. اگر سطح خودکارآمدی پایین باشد، آینده‌نگری هم ضعیف خواهد بود. در نتیجه، ترس از موفقیت پدید می‌آید و جلوی پیشرفت و ارتقای توانایی رسیدن به اهداف را می‌گیرد.</li>
<li><strong>خجالتی بودن/اضطراب داشتن:</strong> گاهی دلیل بروز ترس از موفقیت آنقدر هم پیچیده نیست و به خجالتی بودن یا ابتلا به اختلال مرسوم اضطراب برمی‌گردد. در چنین شرایطی شخص مایل نیست توجه زیادی را به خود جلب کند، بنابراین موقعیت‌های اندکی برای کسب موفقیت پیدا می‌کند که پرداختن به هر کدام با اضطراب همراه می‌شود. بهترین راهکار برای بهبود این شرایط، مراجعه‌ی مستمر به روان‌درمانگر است.</li>
</ul>
<h2>تأثیرهای منفی پدیده‌ی ترس از موفقیت</h2>
<p><img loading="lazy" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-1085828" src="./sample_files/anxiety-1.png" alt="اضطراب و دل‌مشغولی" width="822" height="522" srcset="https://www.digikala.com/mag/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/anxiety-1.png 822w, https://www.digikala.com/mag/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/anxiety-1-300x191.png 300w, https://www.digikala.com/mag/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/anxiety-1-768x488.png 768w, https://www.digikala.com/mag/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/anxiety-1-190x122.png 190w, https://www.digikala.com/mag/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/anxiety-1-120x76.png 120w, https://www.digikala.com/mag/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/anxiety-1-265x168.png 265w, https://www.digikala.com/mag/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/anxiety-1-284x180.png 284w, https://www.digikala.com/mag/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/anxiety-1-274x173.png 274w, https://www.digikala.com/mag/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/anxiety-1-220x140.png 220w" sizes="(max-width: 822px) 100vw, 822px"></p>
<p id="mntl-sc-block_1-0-28" class="comp mntl-sc-block mntl-sc-block-adslot mntl-block">ترس از موفقیت در کنار آسیب‌هایی که به وجهه‌ی اجتماعی شخص وارد می‌کند، می‌تواند کیفیت زندگی را هم دستخوش تغییرهای منفی کند. بعضی از این تأثیرهای منفی به شرح زیر هستند.</p>
<ul>
<li><strong>کاهش سطح رضایت از زندگی:</strong> ترس از موفقیت با از دست دادن موقعیت‌هایی همراه است که هر کدام می‌توانند نقشی اساسی در متحول کردن شرایط زندگی شخص ایفا کنند. بدون شک هنگامی که کسب موفقیت ممکن نباشد، سطح رضایت از زندگی کاهش می‌یابد و شخص وارد چرخه‌ی باطلی می‌شود که انگار نمی‌توان هیچ پایانی برای آن متصور شد.</li>
<li><strong>مواجهه با دشواری در مسیر رسیدن به اهداف:</strong> همیشه برداشتن نخستین قدم‌ها برای شروع دشوار است، اما اگر شخص نتواند از مرحله‌ی اول گذر کند، هیچ تضمینی برای به دست آوردن موفقیت در آینده وجود نخواهد داشت. ترس از موفقیت جلوی آزمایش و خطا، که برای یافتن مسیر درست موفقیت لازم است، را می‌گیرد و موانع زیادی بر سر راه پیشبرد اهداف قرار می‌دهد.</li>
<li><strong>کاهش سطح عزت‌نفس:</strong> کسب موفقیت تأثیر بسزایی روی افزایش میزان عزت‌نفس دارد، بنابراین ترس از موفقیت می‌تواند نقش پررنگی در کاهش سطح عزت‌نفس و از بین بردن انگیزه برای داشتن آینده‌ای بهتر ایفا کند. این موضوع به خصوص درباره‌ی افرادی که از سندروم ایمپاستر رنج می‌برند صادق است، زیرا این افراد عموما دستاوردهای خود را نتیجه‌ی دانش، توانایی و پشتکار خود نمی‌بینند.</li>
<li><strong>کم‌توقع بودن:</strong> کم‌توقعی و دوری جستن از موقعیت‌هایی که به موفقیت‌های بزرگ ختم می‌شوند می‌توانند شخص را به رکود عادت دهند و ترس از موفقیت را تشدید کنند.</li>
</ul>
<h2>درمان پدیده‌ی ترس از موفقیت</h2>
<p>خوشبختانه درمان این پدیده با استفاده از شیوه‌های روان‌درمانی ممکن است. یکی از بهترین راهکارها برای بهبود سلامت ذهن و کمرنگ کردن ترس از موفقیت، روان‌کاوی است. در این شیوه، مشکل‌ها و اختلال‌های موجود در زندگی با توجه به ریشه‌ای که در دوران کودکی دارند بررسی می‌شوند و در اغلب مواقع، نتایج بسیار سودمندی حاصل می‌شود.</p>
<p>یک شیوه‌ی مؤثر دیگر برای از بین بردن ترس از موفقیت، درمان شناختی-رفتاری است. در این شیوه محرک‌های منفی که باعث بروز رفتارهای مخرب می‌شوند شناسایی شده و طی چندین جلسه‌ی درمانی بررسی و درمان می‌شوند. درمان شناختی-رفتاری به شخص این فرصت را می‌دهد که الگوهای رفتاری خود را بشناسد و آن‌ها را بر اساس میزان سودمندی تفکیک کند. ممکن است این دو شیوه‌ی درمانی با مصرف دارو همراه باشند، اما تا زمانی که داروها به موقع و به درستی مصرف شوند، جای هیچ نگرانی نیست.</p>
<p>به غیر از شیوه‌های روان‌درمانی، راهکارهای مؤثر دیگری هم برای کنار آمدن با ترس از موفقیت وجود دارند که در ادامه به آن‌ها می‌پردازیم.</p>
<h3>۱. مقابله با استرس</h3>
<p><img loading="lazy" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-1085831" src="./sample_files/stress.png" alt="مبارزه با استرس" width="822" height="522" srcset="https://www.digikala.com/mag/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/stress.png 822w, https://www.digikala.com/mag/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/stress-300x191.png 300w, https://www.digikala.com/mag/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/stress-768x488.png 768w, https://www.digikala.com/mag/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/stress-190x122.png 190w, https://www.digikala.com/mag/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/stress-120x76.png 120w, https://www.digikala.com/mag/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/stress-265x168.png 265w, https://www.digikala.com/mag/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/stress-284x180.png 284w, https://www.digikala.com/mag/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/stress-274x173.png 274w, https://www.digikala.com/mag/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/stress-220x140.png 220w" sizes="(max-width: 822px) 100vw, 822px"></p>
<p>استرس یکی از مهم‌ترین عوامل ایجاد ترس، از هر نوعی، است و می‌تواند باعث بروز ترس از موفقیت هم بشود. از این رو، فراگیری راهکارهای ساده اما مؤثر مقابله با استرس ضروری است. به هنگام مضطرب شدن، نفس عمیق بکشید و ساکن نمانید، سعی کنید در حد پیاده‌روی ملایم هم که شده تحرک داشته باشید. در افکارتان، مکان امن و شادی‌آوری را تصور کنید و حین تمرکز روی نحوه‌ی تنفس، عضلات منقبض‌شده را شل کنید.</p>
<ul>
<li class="_txt entry-title"><a href="https://www.digikala.com/mag/stress-management-techniques/">۵ تکنیک مدیریت استرس که تأثیر آن‌ها اثبات شده است</a></li>
</ul>
<h3 id="mntl-sc-block_1-0-61" class="comp mntl-sc-block mntl-sc-block-adslot mntl-block">۲. شناسایی احساس‌های منفی</h3>
<p class="comp mntl-sc-block mntl-sc-block-adslot mntl-block">یکی دیگر از راهکارهای مناسب برای مقابله با این ترس، شناسایی و بررسی احساس‌های منفی و محرک‌هایشان است. سعی کنید به محیط اطرافتان توجه بیشتری داشته باشید و هنگامی که درگیر احساس‌های منفی می‌شوید، آن‌ها را ریشه‌یابی کنید. برای این منظور، می‌توانید از دوستان و آشنایان نزدیک هم کمک بگیرید و از آن‌ها بخواهید احساس‌هایتان را از دیدگاهی دیگر ارزیابی کنند. گاهی ارزیابی خود از دیدگاه دیگران می‌تواند به روشن شدن مسائل بسیاری کمک کند.</p>
<h3 id="mntl-sc-block_1-0-67" class="comp mntl-sc-block mntl-sc-block-adslot mntl-block">۳. افزایش آستانه‌ی تحمل</h3>
<p class="comp mntl-sc-block mntl-sc-block-adslot mntl-block">ترس از موفقیت باعث بروز رفتارهای اجتنابی می‌شود و آستانه‌ی تحمل دشواری در مواجهه با وقایع زندگی و دیگران را پایین می‌آورد. بنابراین، یکی از راهکارهای درمان ترس از موفقیت، انجام تمرین‌هایی برای افزایش آستانه‌ی تحمل است. دفعه‌ی بعدی که درگیر احساس‌های منفی و ناخوانده شدید، سعی کنید مسیر راحت‌تر را انتخاب نکنید. به جای فرار کردن از احساس‌ها و عواقب‌شان، آن‌ها را بپذیرید. انجام این کار خوشایند نیست، اما در بلندمدت آستانه‌ی تحمل را افزایش می‌دهد و مدیریت ترس از موفقیت را ساده‌تر می‌کند.</p>
<h2>مرور کلی</h2>
<p>ترس از موفقیت رسیدن به اهداف را دشوار می‌کند و به عزت‌نفس و اعتمادبه‌نفس آسیب‌های جدی وارد می‌کند. خوشبختانه، راهکارهایی برای کنار آمدن با این ترس وجود دارد که، در صورت استمرار، می‌توانند آن را به کل از بین ببرند. در این میان، افزایش آستانه‌ی تحمل دشواری‌ها و مقابله با استرس از اهمیت والایی برخوردار هستند. فراموش نکنید که مراجعه به روان‌درمانگر را حتما در دستور کار خود قرار دهید.</p>
<div class="base-box">این مطلب فقط جنبه‌ی آموزش و اطلاع‌رسانی دارد. پیش از استفاده از توصیه‌های این مطلب حتما با یک متخصص مشورت کنید. برای اطلاعات بیشتر <a href="https://www.digikala.com/mag/disclaimer/"><strong>بیانیه‌ی رفع مسؤولیت دیجی‌کالا مگ</strong></a> را بخوانید.</div>
<p>منبع: <a href="https://www.verywellmind.com/what-is-the-fear-of-success-5179184" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Verywellmind</a></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="post-module__social dialog">
```

So with that input , I'm trying to reach something like this("##number" instead of html tags(I didn't put the the whole sample again))

```
                ##172
                                                        ##172
##172کسب موفقیت یکی از ارکان اصلی داشتن یک زندگی باکیفیت محسوب می‌شود. انسان‌ها ذاتا موجوداتی اجتماعی هستند و هنگامی که در جامعه در کنار سایر هم‌نوعانشان قرار می‌گیرند، میل شدیدی به قرار گرفتن در بالات
رین نقطه‌ی سلسله‌مراتب اجتماعی پیدا می‌کنند. از دیرباز تا کنون، کسب موفقیت به عنوان یکی از باارزش‌ترین و ستودنی‌ترین موارد تلاش بشر در جوامع مختلف، از اهمیت بسیاری برخوردار بوده است. با این وجود، گهگاه
 فشار وارده بر انسان برای داشتن اهداف والایی که قادر هستند او را به سمت موفقیت سوق دهند به قدری زیاد می‌شود که میل به کسب موفقیت جای خود را به ترس از موفقیت می‌دهد.##172
##172نکته‌ی قابل تأمل در رابطه با پدیده‌ی ترس از موفقیت این است که مفهوم موفقیت به‌خودی‌خود هراس‌برانگیز نیست. در واقع، ترسی که در قلب عواقب احتمالی ناشی از دست‌یابی به موفقیت واقع شده است آن را تبدیل 
به پدیده‌ای ناخوشایند می‌کند. با هر بار کسب موفقیت، انتظارهای دیگران برای کسب موفقیت‌های بزرگ‌تر بیشتر می‌شود و به موازات آن، نگرانی در خصوص از دست دادن آرامش به قیمت ارتقای موقعیت اجتماعی هم افزایش می
‌یابد. با این اوصاف، می‌توان به جرأت گفت که بروز پدیده‌ی ترس از موفقیت بی‌خود و بی‌جهت نیست.##172
##172در این مقاله از دیجی‌کالا مگ، ضمن معرفی ویژگی‌های این پدیده، راهکارهایی برای شناسایی و درمان آن ارائه می‌کنیم. با ما همراه باشید.##172
##172
##172
```

but instead of 172, it would be numbers from 1 to 172

Thanks in advance

Comment: "I'm trying to remove all HTML tags from a text file and after some processing on the text , I have to put the HTML tags back in the text" -- why use regex? An HTML parser like BeautifulSoup should be far easier and more accurate. That said, it's hard to help without seeing the input and output markup.

Comment: well , we are already using BeautifulSoup to scarp the data from a website , and it does a fine job removing the tags using "lxml" but i have to mark the place of occurrences so i can replace the tags back in the file and post it on another website, but after manipulating and cutting the input into sperate pieces, i have no idea how to put them back in place @ggorlen

Comment: As suggested, I would share the context for what you're trying to accomplish and leave the tools open for discussion to avoid the [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676). What's the input HTML you're working with (a minimal example, please) and what output are you trying to achieve? You can [edit] your post. Thanks.

Comment: sure no problem , I haven't connected this script with the scraping part but i can share a sample I'm working with right now @ggorlen

Comment: Is the sample not good enough ? @ggorlen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after a while it turned out to be a hard process with minimum rewards(a lot of work for accomplishing almost nothing in return)
However I found a working solution that I will share in some steps
(keep in mind that this code was suppose to do some text processing(NLP) and after ward upload the required amount of context into another website )
I can't provide the exact codes but I will try to explain the algorithm that could be working in a situation like this:

```
1- Make an exact html template of the first site (jninja or else).
2- Get rid of html tags.
3- Do whatever you need with the context .
4- Replacing each part of the context according to the first website in the template using regex.
5- Saving the original and manipulated text ,the amount of the first upload and ....
in some sort of DB 
6- Uploading the the required amount of text into the second website
```

Sorry that it's vaguely explained but really the only important part is making the template and marking it to replace with the desired text hence only working on a particular website.